# Execute code only when JFrame is visible on screen executes earlier

Tags: java, swing, jframe, splash-screen

I have a `JFrame` called `splash_window` that I am using as a **splash screen** for my app and it displays first. It has a `progress bar` which is at `0%` at first and I want it to change to `5%` and execute some other commands as soon as it becomes visible to the **user**.
When I run the app the app, `the progress bar`'s progress is *already* at `5%` **before** my `splash screen` becomes visible and I can see in the console that my other commands are being executed.
My question is this: How can I make it so that the commands will be executed as soon as the `splash screen` becomes visible to the user **on screen**?

My code:

```
//making the splash_window visible after adding all components to it
splash_window.setVisible(true);

//Used to detect when the splash_window is visible to the user
if (splash_window.isShowing()){

    //Used to know if the splash_window is visible
    System.out.print("Splash screen is complete and now visible." + System.lineSeparator());

    //Method used to increase my progress by 5%
    initProgress.setValue(getProgress(5));

    //Other commands...
}
```

Comment: 1) For s splash screen, look at [`SplashScreen`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/SplashScreen.html) 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Use a combination of WindowListener and a Timer, as the WindowListener may be notified before the window is actually realised on the screen due to OS overheads

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a window listener to the frame and update the progress when the window is opened. Here is an example:

```
splash_window.addWindowListener(new WindowListener() {

        @Override
        public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {
            initProgress.setValue(getProgress(5));
            initProgress.revalidate();
        }

        ...

    });
```